# Bukkit Check Player's Inventory

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to see if a player has any of the following items in their inventory, and if they do, I want to remove the items and send them a message saying  the item has been removed but I cannot figure out how to do it, this is what I have so far:

```
    Material[] bannedItems = { Material.DIAMOND_HELMET, Material.DIAMOND_CHESTPLATE, Material.DIAMOND_LEGGINGS, Material.DIAMOND_BOOTS, Material.GOLD_HELMET, Material.GOLD_CHESTPLATE, Material.GOLD_LEGGINGS, Material.GOLD_BOOTS };

@EventHandler
public void onInventoryClick(InventoryClickEvent event) {
    Player player = (Player) event.getWhoClicked();
    if(player.getInventory().contains(bannedItems, 1)){
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "[" + ChatColor.RED + ChatColor.BOLD + "RPG" + ChatColor.GRAY + "] " + ChatColor.RED + "A has been removed from your possession.");
    }
}
```

I get an error on the .contains(bannedItems, 1)) line.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What error? Please explain further. An event such as when they pick up an item would probably more practical in this case

Comment: I'm being told I have to change the Material[] to a int but then that gives me errors saying I have to change it from a int to a Material[]

Comment: int[] is for int arrays, Material[] is for material arrays... You must iterate over the array and check each

Comment: I don't suppose you could explain further?

Comment: When doing a contains check, you don't supply an array type. You supply a single type. You must have a loop to iterate over the material array to check each element of the array to the current item in inventory

Comment: How would I do this for every single item in the list? I only know how to pick out a random item which isn't useful for this situation.

Comment: Let me write you a proof of concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every element in the array, you must check it, not just compare the array. Here is a proof of concept:

```
double[] check = {1.3, 4.2, 4.3}; //A sample double array

for(double d : check) { //Loop thru all elements
    if(4.2 == d) { //If current element is equal to 4.2
        System.out.println("EQUAL!"); //Print "EQUAL!"
    }
}
```

This loops over the `check` array one-by-one and compares each element to 4.2. It them reports when they are equal. You can then apply this to this situation:

```
@EventHandler
public void onInventoryClick(InventoryClickEvent event) {
    Material[] bannedItems = { Material.DIAMOND_HELMET, Material.DIAMOND_CHESTPLATE, Material.DIAMOND_LEGGINGS, Material.DIAMOND_BOOTS, Material.GOLD_HELMET, Material.GOLD_CHESTPLATE, Material.GOLD_LEGGINGS, Material.GOLD_BOOTS };
    Player player = (Player) event.getWhoClicked();

    for(Material m : bannedItems) { //Loop thru all elements
        if(player.getInventory().contains(m, 1)){ //Check if in inventory
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "[" + ChatColor.RED + ChatColor.BOLD + "RPG" + ChatColor.GRAY + "] " + ChatColor.RED + "A has been removed from your possession.");
            //Remove stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the event will loop through each element of the `bannedItems` and check if the user has it in there inventory.

```
for(Material m : bannedItems)
```

Is an enhanced for loop that stores the current element in `bannedItems` in the `m` variable and then we compare using `m`, a single material.

I would also use a different event, such as when they pick up an item, and then check, so you can remove it right away.

Comment: Thank you very much for not only the answer, but a full explanation too! This has really helped me.

Comment: No problem, we're all here to learn :) Let me know if you've got any other questions